# Alterar tela pelo arquivo python em kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-kivy

Preciso alterar a tela dentro do arquivo **.py**, não consigo fazer isso pelo **.kv** pois tenho que usar o `ButtonBehavior` e ele não funciona no **.kv**.

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
    from kivy.uix.image import Image, AsyncImage
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

    import json
    import requests


    class TelaInicio(Screen):
        pass


    class TelaLigas(Screen):
        def on_enter(self, *args):
            url = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ligas')
            res = json.loads(url.text)
            for i in res:
                self.ids.ligas.add_widget(ListaLigas(ligas=i['imagem']))


    class TelaTorneios(Screen):
        pass


    class ListaLigas(BoxLayout, ButtonBehavior, Image):
        def __init__(self, ligas, manager=None, **kwargs):
            super(ListaLigas, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.manager = manager
            self.l = str(ligas)
            self.add_widget(AsyncImage(source=self.l))

        def on_press(self):
            print('ok')
            self.manager.troca_tela_torneios()


    class Manager(ScreenManager):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(Manager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.lista_ligas = ListaLigas(self)

        def troca_tela_torneios(self):
            self.current = 'tela_torneios'

        def troca_tela_ligas(self):
            self.current = 'tela_ligas'

        def troca_tela_inicio(self):
            self.current = 'tela_inicio'


    class Main(App):
        def build(self):
            return Manager()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Main().run()
```

O erro:

> File "/home/marcelo/PycharmProjects/EAnimaApp/main.py", line 36, in
>   on_press
>        self.manager.troca_tela_torneios()  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'troca_tela_torneios'

Comment: Quando você instancia `ListaLigas` em `Manager` você passa apenas um parâmetro, que será `ligas` e, portanto, `manager` permanecerá `None`.

Comment: Entendi mais ou menos, agora, como eu posso passar os dois parâmetros? eu ainda estou aprendo, aprendi essa parada do __init__ ontem e fiquei impressionado.